# Asking for input until it is valid in C

Tags: c, validation, scanf

I'm not asking for a solution but rather for an explanation.

I'd like to understand why this enters an infinite loop (printing "Escolha um ano" non-stop) if the input is invalid.

```
while(error)
{
   puts("Escolha um ano:");

   if(scanf(" %d", &ano)!= 1)
   {
      puts("Escolheu mal o ano. Tente de novo");
   }
   else error = 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you inputting?

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: I want to input a year, but if I input a char, for example it goes ape shit.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm using the terminal, haven't tried to debug it.

Comment: Then you should do so.